# Use of namespace import PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

Why does my namespace import don't override the namespace import I used in the parent class?

```
// parent class
namespace Base\Models\Products;

use \Base\Models\Products\ProductVariant;

Class Product {
    public function setVariants($data){
        new ProductVariant();
    }
}

// child class
namespace CMS\Models\Products;

use \CMS\Models\Products\ProductVariant;

Class Product extends \Base\Models\Products\Product {
  function save(){
    // do something
  }
}

$product = new \CMS\Models\Products\Product();
$product->setVariants(array('waarde1','waarde2'));
$product->save();
```

It returns:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Base\Models\Products\ProductVariant::save()
>
> It should be Cms\Models\Products\ProductVariant::save()

Thanks in advance!

Comment: read the PHP manual on namespaces and importing.

Comment: Sorry but I can't find the answer for this when extending a already imported a namespace. It seems like it will not be overwritten.

Comment: well if you can't find your answers in the Official PHP manaul then you are out of luck because you missed it.

Comment: When you are doing the `$product->setVariants()` you got a new object ProductVariant() which don't have the function save. I guess it' more an architecture issue.

Comment: what is happening is that base class .. is set ... once you declare it it will use what you declared for it.  im just not sure why you want to change the class that it uses internally.